# sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, ssh-tunnel

My network architecture (unchangeable):
*pc* --ssh--> *serv* --ssh--> *serv_mod* --telnet--> *serv_submod*
For now, I am trying to use ssh tunneling from *pc* to *serv_mod*

*pc* `'10.42.100.2' 'pc_user' 'pc_pass'`

*serv* `'10.42.100.4' 'serv_user' 'serv_pass'`

*serv_mod* `'127.0.0.1' 'serv_mod_user' 'serv_mod_pass'`

*serv_submod* `telnet 192.168.252.100 2323`

Now I am trying to access *serv_submod* from *pc*, however it overcomes me a bit. I have tried to use ssh tunneler to reach *serv_mod* first, but I have following error:

```
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway



with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('10.42.100.4', 22),
        ssh_username='serv_user',
        ssh_password='serv_pass',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    ):
        logger.debug('ssh tunnel estabilished')
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect('127.0.0.1', 22)
        client.close()
```

Can you help me solve this issue and maybe suggest proper way to connect 'directly' to *serv_submod*

Thank you in advance